# How to fix input devices after xserver-xorg-core upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, xorg

When I start my Dell Inspiron 7566 laptop and Kubuntu login screen is displayed it turns out that keyboard and mouse do not work. X complains:

```
[    16.130] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event3)
[    16.130] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    16.130] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    16.130] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Video Bus (/dev/input/event7)
[    16.130] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    16.130] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    16.130] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Video Bus (/dev/input/event8)
[    16.130] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    16.130] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    16.130] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event1)
[    16.130] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    16.130] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    16.130] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Lid Switch (/dev/input/event0)
[    16.130] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    16.130] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    16.130] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Sleep Button (/dev/input/event2)
[    16.130] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    16.130] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    16.131] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Holtek USB Gaming Mouse (/dev/input/event5)
[    16.131] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    16.131] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    16.131] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Holtek USB Gaming Mouse (/dev/input/event6)
[    16.131] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    16.131] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    16.131] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Holtek USB Gaming Mouse (/dev/input/mouse0)
[    16.131] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    16.131] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    16.131] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Integrated Webcam (/dev/input/event17)
[    16.131] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    16.131] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    16.132] (II) config/udev: Adding input device 2.4G Gaming Dongle (/dev/input/event9)
[    16.132] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    16.132] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    16.132] (II) config/udev: Adding input device 2.4G Gaming Dongle (/dev/input/mouse1)
[    16.132] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    16.132] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    16.132] (II) config/udev: Adding input device 2.4G Gaming Dongle (/dev/input/event10)
[    16.132] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    16.132] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    16.132] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Headphone Mic (/dev/input/event12)
[    16.132] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    16.132] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    16.132] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event13)
[    16.132] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    16.132] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    16.132] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event14)
[    16.132] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    16.132] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    16.133] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 (/dev/input/event15)
[    16.133] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    16.133] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    16.133] (II) config/udev: Adding input device AT Translated Set 2 keyboard (/dev/input/event4)
[    16.133] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    16.133] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    16.133] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/event11)
[    16.133] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    16.133] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    16.133] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/mouse2)
[    16.133] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    16.133] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    16.134] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Dell WMI hotkeys (/dev/input/event16)
[    16.134] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    16.134] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
```

This problem was most likely introduced by yesterdays upgrade of  [xserver-xorg-core to 2:1.18.4-0ubuntu0.1](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/powerpc/xserver-xorg-core/2:1.18.4-0ubuntu0.1). It seems that this package conflicts/breaks a number of packages related to input handling. Upgrade log:

```
Start-Date: 2017-03-09  16:49:09
Install: xserver-xorg-core:amd64 (2:1.18.4-0ubuntu0.2, automatic)
Upgrade: libnm-glib4:amd64 (1.2.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.4, 1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libgtk-3-common:amd64 (3.18.9-1ubuntu3.1, 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.2), libgtk-3-0:amd64 (3.18.9-1ubuntu3.1, 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.2), primus-libs:amd64 (0~20150328-1, 20150328-3~xenialppa1), primus-libs:i386 (0~20150328-1, 20150328-3~xenialppa1), libnm0:amd64 (1.2.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.4, 1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), network-manager:amd64 (1.2.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.4, 1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libnm-util2:amd64 (1.2.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.4, 1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libxnvctrl0:amd64 (378.09-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1, 378.13-0ubuntu0~gpu16.10.2), libgtk-3-bin:amd64 (3.18.9-1ubuntu3.1, 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.2), primus-libs-ia32:i386 (0~20150328-1, 20150328-3~xenialppa1), bumblebee:amd64 (3.2.1-10, 3.2.1-96~xenialppa1), nvidia-settings:amd64 (378.09-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1, 378.13-0ubuntu0~gpu16.10.2)
Remove: xserver-xorg-video-qxl-hwe-16.04:amd64 (0.1.4-3ubuntu3~16.04.1), xserver-xorg-video-vesa-hwe-16.04:amd64 (1:2.3.4-1build2~16.04.1), xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-hwe-16.04:amd64 (1.1.2-1~16.04.1), primus:amd64 (0~20150328-1), xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-16.04:amd64 (1.8.3-1ubuntu1~16.04.1), xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04:amd64 (1:7.7+13ubuntu4~16.04.2), xserver-xorg-video-all-hwe-16.04:amd64 (1:7.7+13ubuntu4~16.04.2), xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-hwe-16.04:amd64 (1:0.4.4-1build5~16.04.1), xserver-xorg-video-vmware-hwe-16.04:amd64 (1:13.1.0-2ubuntu3~16.04.1), xorg:amd64 (1:7.7+13ubuntu3), xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-16.04:amd64 (2:2.99.917+git20160706-1ubuntu1~16.04.1), xserver-xorg-core-hwe-16.04:amd64 (2:1.18.4-1ubuntu6.1~16.04.1), xserver-xorg-input-wacom-hwe-16.04:amd64 (1:0.33.0-0ubuntu1~16.04.1), xserver-xorg-input-evdev-hwe-16.04:amd64 (1:2.10.2-1ubuntu1~16.04.1), xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-hwe-16.04:amd64 (1:1.0.12-2~16.04.1), xserver-xorg-input-all-hwe-16.04:amd64 (1:7.7+13ubuntu4~16.04.2), xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-16.04:amd64 (1:7.7.1-1~16.04.1), xserver-xorg-video-ati-hwe-16.04:amd64 (1:7.7.1-1~16.04.1)
End-Date: 2017-03-09  16:51:18

Start-Date: 2017-03-09  16:55:20
Install: libindicator7:amd64 (12.10.2+16.04.20151208-0ubuntu1, automatic), libindicator3-7:amd64 (12.10.2+16.04.20151208-0ubuntu1, automatic), libappindicator3-1:amd64 (12.10.1+16.04.20170215-0ubuntu1, automatic), libappindicator1:amd64 (12.10.1+16.04.20170215-0ubuntu1), libdbusmenu-gtk3-4:amd64 (16.04.1+16.04.20160927-0ubuntu1, automatic), indicator-application:amd64 (12.10.1+16.04.20170120-0ubuntu1, automatic)
End-Date: 2017-03-09  16:55:21
```

How can I fix missing input drivers in X server? Can I avoid downgrade of the problematic package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely this will be fixed by running

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-input-all-hwe-16.04
```

You have a new HWE stack, but installed an old `xserver-xorg-core`.

There are two packages that represent user space graphical stack. `xserver-xorg` and `xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04`. They both have a lot of dependencies.

And they replace each other when you install them. So if you have the `hwe-16.04` stack, you need all `xserver-xorg-*` packages to be with `-hwe-16.04`.

Comment: I have compared what live cd of Kubuntu uses with current state and came to conclusion that I need to install `xserver-xorg-core-hwe-16.04`. However then I noticed that xserver-xorg-core gets removed and there are some missing dependencies of `xserver-xorg-core-hwe-16.04`. So I thought I was not doing the right thing. Could you elaborate more on difference between `HWE` and the old `xserver-xorg-core`? Why did xserver-xorg-core got installed automatically? Hmm it looks like `bumblebee` depends on it... Do I have to resign from  NVIDIA Optimus then?

Comment: Your `xserver-xorg-core` got installed either because some dependency is set wrong in some package from a PPA, or some other reason. You should not have it installed.

Comment: Hmm it looks like `bumblebee` depends on `xserver-xorg-core`... Do I have to resign from NVIDIA Optimus then?

Comment: Bumblebee does not work well on new versions of Ubuntu. You can use `nvidia-prime` instead. If you need bumblebee that badly and it really works for you, then roll back to the initial stack by installing `xserver-xorg`.

Comment: And I do not see that `bumblebee` from the official repos depend on `xserver-xorg-core`.

Comment: My `bumblebee` is in `3.2.1-96~xenialppa1` version. To be honest I do not know why I have it on my laptop. Most likely admin who installed system tried to make the NVIDIA card work and started from this and then it moved to `nvidia-prime`. Yesterday during startup packages remove or upgrade it all somehow happened automagically...

Comment: This is an unofficial package. Remove that PPA from the upgrade list.

Comment: Is it also better to remove `http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu`? BTW running command in the answer fixed the problem.

Comment: You can keep the `graphics-drivers` PPA, if you have no problems with those drivers. It is not related.